# How to change MM:HH:SS to minute while the variable tupe are <char>

Tags: r, time, type-conversion, dataset, minute

My dataset "ride_history" has a variable name "total_time_spend". Here the values are in HH:MM:SS (example:  03:26:30) format and the variable type is "char". I want to convert it into a new variable
"minute" and add it in the dataset.
How to do it?

I have used "separate" function to make new colum Hour,minute,sec. But those column are not "numeric". That's why I use "as.numeric" to calculate a new variable "total_minute". After that, I used "cbind" to make new dataset!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `hms` and `lubridate` packages you could do:

```r
library(hms)
library(lubridate)

dat <- data.frame(
  total_time_spend = "03:26:30"
)

dat$minute <- lubridate::minute(hms::as_hms(dat$total_time_spend))

str(dat)
#> 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ total_time_spend: chr "03:26:30"
#>  $ minute          : int 26
```

**EDIT** A second option would be to use `tidyr::separate` to split the time string into its components:

```r
dat |> 
  tidyr::separate(total_time_spend, into = c("hour", "minute", "second"), sep = ":", 
           convert = TRUE, remove = FALSE)
#> Warning: Expected 3 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 1 rows [2].
#>   total_time_spend hour minute second
#> 1         03:26:30    3     26     30
#> 2            04:27    4     27     NA
```

Comment: final$minutes<-lubridate::minute(hms::as_hms(final$ride_length))
Results::::::Error in `abort_lossy_cast()`:
! Lossy cast from <character> to <hms> at position(s) 6930, 8232, 10753, 18139, 18358, ... (and 5500 more)
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: How to solve this?

Comment: Hi @SaifulIslam. The issue is most likely that some (or a lot of, i.e. approx. 5500) of the character values in your `ride_length` column are not in the proper format. For example if the seconds or the hours are missing like in `"04:27"` you will get an error. The general approach to fix that would be to complete the character strings e.g. add a `00:` or a `:00`. But a a first step this requires to figure out which part (hours or seconds) is missing in your data.